# Uncaught ReferenceError when adding JS to app.js in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, laravel-mix, browser-detection

I have some browser sniffer code using the function [detect.js](https://github.com/darcyclarke/Detect.js/blob/master/detect.js). It works fine when not added to my project. Still, when I try to compile the JavaScript and add it to app.js, I get an error in the console at the first line below, refreshing the browser and detecting the browser version.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: forEach is not defined.

```
// Each Utility
var each = forEach = function (obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj == null) return;
    if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
        obj.forEach(iterator, context);
    } else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
        for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
            iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj);
        }
    } else {
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (_.has(obj, key)) {
                iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

It seems like compiling the JavaScript is doing something to it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Detect.js has been last updated in 2015. You should not use it in 2021.

Comment: What do you need the browser sniffing for here? We might be able to recommend replacements.

Comment: npm probably scopes the variables. Take a look at the resulting file. Try `window.forEach = function() { ...` instead.

Comment: Good point AKX - I'm looking at detect-browser https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-browser as an option

Comment: Get the similar issue with detect-browser (index):300 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Answer (score 0):

If I use the [detect-browser](https://npmjs.com/package/detect-browser) package.

```
npm i detect-browser
```

Then add the following to my app.js...

```
const { detect } = require('detect-browser');
const browser = detect();

try {
    // handle the case where we don't detect the browser
    if (browser) {
        console.log(browser.name);
        console.log(browser.version);
        console.log(browser.os);
    } else {
        console.log('no browser');
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

And issue an `npm run prod`...

When I pull up the page, I get the following in my console (no errors).

[image]

Comment: I'm sure it does, but the issue must be in a conflict with other js or the webpack compression of the javascript in my laravel-mix setup.